# Prevent certain css elements to apply when using media query

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to make my site responsive but I don't know how to continue. I have a navigation bar with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags that I have set some arguments for in my css. My question is if I am able to disable those arguments when I reach a certain width on the website.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: yes, that's what responsive webdesign is all about. set styles based on width (or other conditions)

Comment: by arguments I suppose you're talking about properties: of course you can set those properties with a max-width mediaquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Sure! You can use media queries to create sensible breakpoints for your layouts and interfaces. These breakpoints are mostly based on viewport widths.
For Example:

```css
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
li {
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    &:first-child {
      padding-top: 0;
    }
  }
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { li {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    &:first-child {
      padding-top: 1rem;
    }
  }}

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width
```